# R code for estimating a Poisson parameter and its CI?

Tags: r, estimation, poisson-distribution

What is the R code to estimate the parameter lambda of the Poisson distribution?

I tried

```
# of occurrence 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
occ  <- 0:7 
# of sequence 150, 200, 220, 230, 240, 250, 180, 260
freq <- c(150,200,220,230,240,250,180,260)
mean_per_seq <- occ %*% freq
```

Is this correct?

What is the R code to find 95 % confidence interval of the parameter lambda?

Comment: I fixed the formatting problems with your R excerpt, Sarah, but it still doesn't seem to be valid: you should edit it.  Also, it seems that in the last two lines you try to present your data, but what exactly do they mean?  Are you trying to say you observed a $0$ 150 times, a $1$ 200 times, ..., and a $7$ 260 times?  It seems so, but if that's the case you definitely do not have a Poisson distribution and estimating its parameter is meaningless (or deceptive).

Comment: I revised more heavily to make the question more comprehensible, feel free to revert or clarify.

Comment: @mkt why was this question closed?

Answer (score 4):

whuber is correct that your data are not Poisson distributed.  But for the record, one answer to your question is to use fit a generalized linear model.  eg

```
> x <- rpois(1000,5)
> model <- glm(x~1, family="poisson")
> exp(coef(model))
(Intercept) 
      5.032 # close to the correct value of 5.000
> exp(confint(model))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
   2.5 %   97.5 % 
4.894243 5.172316
```

With your data, if you did this, you could tell it was not poisson distributed because the estimated dispersion parameter (residual deviance divided by degrees of freedom) is much more than the expected value of one:

```
> y <- rep(0:7, c(150,200,220,230,240,250,180,260))
> table(y)
y
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
150 200 220 230 240 250 180 260 
> model2 <- glm(y~1, family="poisson") 
> summary(model2)

...    
(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2835.1  on 1729  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2835.1  on 1729  degrees of freedom
AIC: 7802.5
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data is:

```
sarahs.data <- c(rep(0, 150), rep(1, 200), 
                 rep(2, 220), rep(3, 230), 
                 rep(4, 240), rep(5, 250), 
                 rep(6, 180), rep(7,260))
```

Then you can use fitdistr from  to find the MLE value of $\lambda$:

```
library(MASS)
parms <- fitdistr(sarahs.data, "poisson")
parms 
        lambda  
3.72254335 
(0.04638706)

lambda <- parms$estimate
sd_x     <- parms$sd
```

To estimate the 95%CI:

```
ci <- c(lambda + c(-1,1) * 1.96 * sd_x)
ci
[1] 3.631625 3.813462
```

Or you can use the fact that [$Var(x)=\lambda=E(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution):

```
lambda <- mean(sarahs.data)
var    <- lambda
sd_x     <- sqrt(sd)/sqrt(length(sarahs.data))
```

To estimate the 95%CI:

```
ci <- c(lambda + c(-1,1) * 1.96 * sd_x)
ci
[1] 3.631625 3.813462
```

As @whuber points out, your data are not distributed as Poisson($\lambda$). Consider the following density plot of a Poisson(3.6) RV:

[image]

Comment: The recipe for a 95%CI given here is wrong. It does not take into account sample size; it would give the same inference from a sample of 10 as for one of size 10,000, if they had the same mean.

Comment: @guest Thanks. I read and answered the question too quickly; updated.

Comment: You can't use `c(lambda + c(-1,1) * 1.96 * sd_x)` for your confidence interval. Try with `set.seed(1); x <- rpois(3, 1)`: you have a negative lower bound for your interval. You should use GLM as Peter Ellis suggests.

Comment: @abichat my answer gives a 95% CI of [3.6,3.8]; not sure I understand your comment about the lower bound being <0? Even if there is a better estimate, is this not sensible?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just interested in the mean of the data (which is what lambda tells you) then with this sample size the Poisson nature of the data is not very important. Using just the central limit theorem, we can use the `t.test()` function to compute a 95% confidence interval;

```
> y <- rep(0:7, c(150,200,220,230,240,250,180,260))
> t.test(y)$conf.int
[1] 3.618070 3.827016`
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

Compare this with the interval you get from a Poisson modeling approach that allows for variance not being equal to the mean;

```
 > model2q <- glm(y~1, family="quasipoisson") 
 > exp( confint.default(model2q) )
               2.5 %   97.5 %
   (Intercept) 3.619594 3.828421
```

...it's almost identical.